# how to send requests via specific network card ip in java, given i haven multiple ips for the same network card

Tags: java, networking, digital-ocean

I am using digital ocean droplet with a floating ip(fip) on top of it.

Anchor ip is the ip droplet uses to communicate with the floating ip

"ip addr" command on my droplet returns 2 ips for ethernet network card, one its public ip(call it ip1) and second its anchor ip(ip2)

when i hit a curl request say "curl clientIp"
client will detect my ip as ip1(the public ip), but when I hit hit the same
command with "curl --interface ip2 clientIp" the ip the client detects is the floating ip(fip)

The idea is i will give the floating ip to my client, so that they can whitelist it and i can remove or add droplets underneath as i wish. I want to implement the same curl behaviour using java code but am not able to.

**I tried this:**

```
RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom().setLocalAddress(InetAddress.getByAddress(ip2)).build();

javax.ws.rs.client.ClientBuilder newBuilder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
                .property(ApacheClientProperties.REQUEST_CONFIG, config);

WebTarget webTarget = newBuilder.build().target(clientUrl);
```

I hit my client url using above code and he detected public ip(ip1) not the floating ip(fip).

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need tu use the ClientBuilder? If you would use Sockets, you cloud specify the ip you want to use.

Comment: its not mandatory to use clientbuilder but we have existing jar which provides classes to makes http requests based on clientbuilder, but if sockets can help i won't mind implementing with sockets on my own

Comment: You can only specify the IP address to use when creating the socket. Either this api u are using is accepting an ip to use or not. If not, you have to create an http request on your own.